# APEX changing row colors in an IG

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

I am following an example I found on-line as since I found it on the internet I know it must be correct.  I am trying to search for a specific value in an IG and when it is found the line/row is highlighted with red text,  Below it the logic I followed and screen shots.  Please let me know what I am missing.  He is using an employee example and I using my car dealership example. Thank you !

```
"Here's another approach that works great:
 For an IR with this query:
 select EMPNO,      ENAME,      JOB,      MGR,      HIREDATE,      SAL,      COMM,      DEPTNO,      
    OFFSITE
 from EMP
 Define for the column JOB the following Static ID: MANAGER_STATIC
 Then create a DA After Refresh on Region where On True Execute the following javascript with Fire 
on Page Load=ON:
this.affectedElements.find('td[headers="MANAGER_STATIC"]').each(function(i) {
var lThis = $(this);
if (lThis.text() == "MANAGER") {
lThis.parent().children().css({
"background-color": "#C0C0C0"
});
}
});
 And every row that has the value of MANAGER will be highlighted and this will respect pagination.
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

That Example appears to be for an Interactive Report, but you appear to be using an Interactive Grid.

The easiest way to do this (without coding) is to run the report and use the Actions Button to define Highlighting. E.G.

[image]

Fill out form similar to this (Change column selection and value to your requirement):
[image]

Afterwards, using the Action Button again to Report->Save the report so it saves the report for All Users.

Comment: This does work but it show a line about the highlight under the navigation tool bar.. This clutters my page. Is there a way to hide it and keep the user from clicking it off?

Comment: Yes, click on your IG, expand and click on Attributes, on the right hand Attributes panel scroll down until you find Advanced->JavaScript Code. Add this javascript (to clear/edit your existing filters, remove this code and re-add it after you have finished): function( options ) {
    options.reportSettingsArea = false;
    return options;
}

Comment: Note: removing the filter section means a user cannot edit their own filters, but if you don't want the user to be performing their own filters, you can Attributes->Toolbar->Show = No to turn the top bar off. IMO If I was to put the above javascript in, I would do so at the same time as turning off the Toolbar, i.e. have either both on or both off. (You can turn them both back on to change the filter as an admin, once finished turn both back off again)